# Finding the repeating weekdays until specific date in JAVA

Tags: java, date, time, calendar

I just started learning Java, and I am having extremely hard time, it just seems so complicated compared to C. 
I have to write a program that detects the current day of the week, and then finds all the remaining same days until specific date. It has to be printed out by the month. So let say its 2016/3/9 now, its Wednesday. The specific date is 2016/4/8. It should print out:
2016/3: 16, 23, 30
2016/4: 6

I am supposed to use java.util.date and java.util.calendar and similar. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Have you tried writing the code yourself? Include your attempts even if does not yield the results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Avoid java.util.Date/.Calendar

FYI, the java.util.Date/.Calendar classes are *terrible*. While well-intentioned, they are poorly designed, confusing, and troublesome. So do not judge Java or your learning by these classes. Indeed, avoid using these classes altogether.

## java.time

The old classes are so bad that Sun/Oracle gave up on them, supplanting them with new classes in the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework. The java.time framework is built into Java 8 and later. See [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

### `LocalDate` class

You want the [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class to represent a date-only without time-of-day and without time zone.

You can instantiate a `LocalDate` by parsing a string or specifying the numbers of the year, month, and day.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse( "2016-04-08" );
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of( 2016 , 4 , 8 );
```

#### Today

Note that determining 'today' requires a time zone even though the resulting `LocalDate` stores no time zone internally. For any given moment, the date may vary around the world by time zone. A new day dawns earlier in Paris than in Montréal.

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) );
```

#### Add Weeks

Add a week to get the next date with the same day-of-week.

```
LocalDate next = today.plusWeeks( 1 );
```

#### Compare `LocalDate`

Compare `LocalDate` objects with the [`isBefore`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#isBefore-java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate-), [`isAfter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#isAfter-java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate-), and [`isEqual`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#isEqual-java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate-) methods.

I will let you put that together to complete your homework assignment.

Also, you can ask a `LocalDate` for a [`DayOfWeek`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) object. That object has handy methods such as [`getDisplayName`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html#getDisplayName-java.time.format.TextStyle-java.util.Locale-) for a localized name of the day-of-week.